# Is there any older text than Valmiki Ramayan that reference Hanuman

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

We know that among the different Ramayans, the oldest one is Valmiki Ramayan. Is there any other text before Valmiki Ramayan that talks about Hanuman? (with reference please).

Answer (score 2):

Have you hear of the text called the Śrī Parāśara Saṃhitā? This book revolves around the history of Lord Hanumān and is said to have been written by Parāśara, the father Vyāsa. So I suppose that it could be older than the Rāmāyaṇa?

Source: [Introduction](https://www.jayahanumanji.com/?p=1969), [Table of contents](http://www.jayahanumanji.com/?p=2091)

Comment: If he is father of sage vyasa as you had suggested the he lived during dwaparayuga only not even thratha yoga when Ramayana was written by valmiki rishi. Your answer us wrong

Comment: Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @prasanna - You have any thoughts? Or you think there is no other older text.

Comment: See @RahulGupta.. you need understand yuga chakra.. when ramayana actually happened.. you need to understand what is manvantra.. whether same avatar is repeated in other manvantra answer is no..  what had happened in another kalpa.. whether same ramayana happened there. Till we have this we are not sure.. if according belief all avatar repeated than there will reference hanuman and rama even before ramayana.. like what we have Kalki avatara.. where we see that its yet happen.. there should be reference Rama and Hanuman before also.. Kalpa->Manvantra->yuga chakra a day of brahma..

Comment: not one mentioned above in the answer

Comment: Wow @PrasannaR - this is interesting though I can't say that I got all of it. Where to begin from? You can point to some of your other answers for reference if you like. And by the way, I know one thing about Hanuman ji - he's present till today (as per the vardan he got from Shri Ram). Therefore I am not sure how the concept of Yuga is applicable in his case.

Comment: Without Hanuman no body survives he vayu avatar, he is the breathing air that you take breath. Hanuman is always present in invisible form one had realised and worship in breathing air. that is why we have tradition called mukhya prana anthargatha lakshmi naraya preranaya and priayartharam This is not just like that simple statements to gloss over require deep thinking of God inside how he operates you.. @RahulGupta..

Comment: Somebody thinks air is free we breath.. why cannot covid patient breath freely when the air free.. God inside mukhya prana is the reason that is the primary life force, last week i read one article about experiement where person tested with feeding oxygen air daily morning 1 hr and evening 1hr ..There aging stopped and infact it got reversed.. We see the obvious results in science, but science doesnt speak the god inside the life air that is vayu.. he is the reason we live @RahulGupta